# Inserting data into SQLITE with commit() statement doesn't work in Python using sqlite3

Tags: python, sqlite, web-crawler

this problem keeps me mad for 2 days...
I cannot insert data into the sqlite file...Here's my script:

```
    sql = f"""INSERT INTO {db_table_name}(aweme_id, author_short_id, author_user_id, author_account_region, author_birthday, 
    author_nickname, author_gender, author_region, author_school_name,
    author_signature, author_uid, author_user_tags, city, create_time, duration, comment_list,
    poi_info_poi_id, poi_info_poi_latitude, poi_info_poi_longitude, poi_info_poi_name,
    statistics_comment_count, statistics_digest, statistics_digg_count, statistics_download_count,
    statistics_exposure_count, statistics_share_count, share_url, status_allow_comment,
    status_allow_share, video_duration, video_allow_download, video_allow_music) 
    VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?);
    """
            
    para = (aweme_id, author_short_id, author_user_id, author_account_region, author_birthday,
                author_nickname, author_gender, author_region, author_school_name,
                author_signature, author_uid, str(author_user_tags), city, create_time, duration, str(comment_list),
                poi_info_poi_id, poi_info_poi_latitude, poi_info_poi_longitude, poi_info_poi_name,
                statistics_comment_count, statistics_digest, statistics_digg_count, statistics_download_count,
                statistics_exposure_count, statistics_share_count, share_url, str(status_allow_comment),
                str(status_allow_share), video_duration, str(video_allow_download), str(video_allow_music))
    try:
        db_cursor.execute(sql, para)
        db_conn.commit()
        print('写入db成功')
        #print(db_cursor.fetchall())
    except Exception as e:
        db_conn.rollback()
        print('写入db失败，回滚事务')
        print(e)
```

I printed the sql and checked the paras, they're all good, the script could run without any error, I couldn't find any problem with the code and I've been searching and trying nearly every solution for similar problems on Stackoverflow. BUT just nothing has been inserted into the table...and the result of fetchall() is always empty...
What's going on...? Thanks a lot if anyone could solve this!

Comment: Your query is not a SELECT statement. There is nothing to be fetched.

Comment: oh thanks~but why is nothing inserted to the table？

Comment: Did you execute a SELECT * FROM ...?

Comment: I used similar code in another script like 2 years ago？Nothing went wrong back then...

Comment: nope, it is just i got some data crawled, and i want to insert them into a sqlite database

Comment: Then how do you know that nothing is inserted?

Comment: If you need more parts of the script, I'll post it in here

Comment: I use Navicat, which is a database viewer, to check whether something is inserted into the table

Comment: What I'm saying is that after the INSERT statement run a SELECT statement to check with fetchall() if the row is inserted. If not, this means that there is an error. Remove the try/catch block to find out.